# Paperclip interpolation for filename db/actual mis-match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I'm making a small app to upload plain text files using Paperclip. I have an `Upload` model that has a document attachment. I want to rename the uploaded file so that it is the same as `Upload.title`.

I've used a Paperclip interpolation to do this.

```
#config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip.interpolates('upload_title') do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.title.parameterize
end

#app/models/upload.rb
has_attached_file :document,
  :url => "/:attachment/:id/:upload_title.:extension",
  :path => ":rails_root/public/:attachment/:id/:upload_title.:extension"
```

However, the file itself is renamed but the `document_file_name` in the database remains as it was.

I've made a test app and uploaded to github [here](https://github.com/garethrees/Uploader/)

Here I create a new `Upload` and attach the file "`Original File Name.txt`"

**garethrees.co.uk/misc/new.JPG**

Here you see the new `Upload` created, still with the original file name.

**garethrees.co.uk/misc/created.JPG**

And also in the database, the `document_file_name` remains the same as it was.

**garethrees.co.uk/misc/db.JPG**

However, in the actual filesystem the document **is** renamed.

**garethrees.co.uk/misc/finder.JPG**

I really need both records to match as I need to use the Paperclip path in order for users to download the files.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create a callback function for after_document_post_process where you set the document_file_name yourself to the title + extension.

Comment: Good idea. I'll use that if I can't find a solution native to Paperclip. Thanks!